# Variable within a bash script

Tags: bash, variables

As debian no longer produces a boot log, I'm attempting to produce one from 'journatctl' (which, I admit, may or may not be the correct course!).
The following script (logdate.sh) works:

```
#!/bin/sh


DATE=$(zenity --entry \
    --title="Produce Log For Chosen Date" \
    --text="Enter date (Mmm nn, e.g. Jul 08)" \
    --entry-text="")
journalctl > /home/john/log && grep -i "${DATE}" log >> /home/john/Logs/log_${DATE}.txt
rm /home/john/log

if zenity --question \
        --text="Do you wish to view to log?"
    then pluma /home/john/Logs/log_"${DATE}".txt
    else zenity --info \
        --text="Log not displayed"
fi
```

---

The variable DATE is passed from the first routine to the second without problem.

However, when trying to modify the code to ensure that users cannot enter an incorrect date format (using zenity), it appears that the variable DATE is not found in the 2nd routine. Code:

```
#!/bin/sh


DATE="$(zenity --calendar --date-format="%b %d" \
--title="Select a Date" \
--text="Click on a date to select that date.")"

if [[ $DATE != "" ]]
    then journalctl > /home/john/log && grep -i "${DATE}" log >> /home/john/Logs/log_'${DATE}'.txt
    rm /home/john/log
    else zenity --info --text="No date selected"
fi

if zenity --question \
    --text="Do you wish to view to log?"
    then pluma /home/john/Logs/log_"${DATE}".txt
    else zenity --info --text="Log not displayed"
fi
```

---

The error message received - 'bash: /home/john/Logs/log_${DATE}.txt: ambiguous redirect' - is due to the fact the DATE is not recognised/picked-up by the second routine

I've tried putting the 2nd & 3rd routines into another script, called from the first script, with the variable DATE being 'exported' from the the 1st, but the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's SOLVED!

Amended

'#!/bin/sh'

to:

'#!/bin/bash'

The first script is obviously not bothered by the omission of 'ba'!

Sorry to have wasted anyone's time. It's my age.